# DELETE all the old rows except the top 20 new

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete all old rows from "idx_links" table  except the 20 newest.
pubDate is timestamp.

This select brings the rows:

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row, t.*
FROM idx_links t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
having(row>20)
ORDER BY pubDate DESC
```

How can I delete this rows?

Answer (score 3):

How about this - delete all rows except the top 20 by pubDate.

```
 DELETE idx_links
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM idx_links 
                  ORDER BY pubDate DESC LIMIT 0,20);
```

Alternately by the date, and avoiding a subquery for the `IN` clause:

```
DELETE idx_links
WHERE pubDate < (SELECT pubDate FROM idx_links 
                 ORDER BY pubDate DESC LIMIT 20,1);
```

Comment: I tried that (because I was giving your same answer) but I'm having this error: `[Err] 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`. I have MySql 5.1.39.

Comment: Anyway, +1 for you because I think this could be a good solution for latest MySql releases...

Comment: Marco, how about finding the 20th pubDate from the top, and deleting all who are older than that (this time by pubDate, rather than ID).

Comment: No, problem is `LIMIT` clause in subquery... but believe me, I don't know how to solve this; consider that removing _LIMIT_ I got an error (but I already knew this) telling me `[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'idx_links' for update in FROM clause`